# Angular 2 scope of Dynamic component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been learning about Angular 2 and their new features and i am having trouble when adding a component dynamically.

so i have a **dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChild }    from '@angular/core';

import { InputTextComponent } from '../input-text/input-text.component'

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    providers: [InputTextComponent],
    styleUrls: ['dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
                 private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
                 private inputTextComponent: InputTextComponent
               ) { }

    @ViewChild(InputTextComponent) textComponent: InputTextComponent

    attachIntup(){
        const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(InputTextComponent);
        const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
        ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }

    alertPop(){
        alert(this.textComponent.passingStr);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

and it has an html code **dashboard.component.html**

```
<button (click)="attachIntup()">Inject Input</button>
<button (click)="alertPop()">Pop String</button>
```

and my **inputTextComponent** is as follows

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-text',
  templateUrl: './input-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-text.component.css']
})
export class InputTextComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  public inputType = '';
  public passingStr = '';

  constructor() { }


  popupAlert(){
    alert(this.passingStr);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.inputType = 'text'
  }

}
```

with an html:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="inputType" class="container">
    <div class="row" *ngSwitchCase="'textarea'">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>I am a textarea: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <textarea style="resize: both" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button (click)="popupAlert()"></button>
            <label>I am an input text: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Testing text" [(ngModel)]="passingStr">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i am trying to do is obtain the scope from the inputTextComponent inside the dashboard component. I have read that the ViewChild allows you to access the variables inside a component, but in my case i am not able to do so.

Does anyone know how i can access the variables inside the InputTextComponent after injection; In order to display in the alert from the dashboard whatever information is been passed through the input.

Thanks in advance